# I cannot passing params to nested navigators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I created TechInfo page and ProfileInfo page ,
ProfileInfo Page inside at Drawer Navigator.
When I entered our info , press button I wantto see some ınfo shows TechInfo page , some info shows ProfileInfo page. But I take error.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View,Text,StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import Login from './Pages/Login';
import SignUP from "./Pages/SignUp";
import TechInfo from "./Pages/TechInfo";
import SplashScreenImage from "./Pages/Splash";
import Publisher from "./Pages/PublisherInfo";
import Profile from "./Pages/ProfileInfo";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator();

function Drawer() {
  return(
    <DrawerNav.Navigator>
      <DrawerNav.Screen name="ProfileInfo" component={Profile} />
      <DrawerNav.Screen name="Hakkımızda" component={Publisher} />
    </DrawerNav.Navigator>
  )
}

function Tab() {
  return(
    <BottomTab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Drawer} />
      <BottomTab.Screen name="TechInfo" component={TechInfo} />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App(){
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName="Splash">
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreenImage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUP} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Tab" component={Tab} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }
})
```

SignUp.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Alert, ScrollView } from "react-native";

import Input from '../components/Input/Input';
import Button from '../components/Button/Button';

function SignUP({ navigation })
    const[userName, setUserName] = useState('');
    const[userLast, setUserLast] = useState('');
    const[userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState('');
    const[userBirth, setUserBirth] = useState('');
    const[userfrom, setUserFrom] = useState('');
    const[userlivein, setUserLivein] = useState('');

    const[useruni, setUserUni] = useState('');
    const[userdeparment, setUserDepartment] = useState('');
    const[userskills, setUserSkills] = useState('');
    const[userusetech, setUserUsetech] = useState('');
    const[userwork, setUserWork] = useState('');
    const[userproject, setUserProject] = useState('');
    const[usergit, setUserGit] = useState('');
    const[userlinkedn, setUserLinkedn] = useState('');
    const[userinstagram, setUserInstagram] = useState('');
    const[userMail, setUserMail] = useState('');

    function handleSubmit() {
        if (!userName || !userLast || !userNumber || !userBirth || !userfrom || !userlivein) {
            Alert.alert('CTC', 'Bilgiler boş bırakılamaz!');
        } else {
            const user = {
                userName,
                userLast,
                userNumber,
                userBirth,
                userfrom,
                userlivein,
            }
            const usertech = {
                useruni,
                userdeparment,
                userskills,
                userusetech,
                userwork,
                userproject,
                usergit,
                userlinkedn,
                userinstagram,
                userMail,
            }
            navigation.navigate('Drawer', { screen: 'ProfileInfo', params: { user } })
            // navigation.navigate('Tab', { screen: 'TechInfo', params: { usertech } })
        } 
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Adı"}
              yazialani={"HASAN KAAN..."}
              onChangeText={setUserName}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Soyadı"} 
              yazialani={"KAHRAMAN..."}
              onChangeText={setUserLast}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Cep Telefonu"} 
              yazialani={"5546439110..."}
              onChangeText={setUserNumber}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Doğum Tarihi"} 
              yazialani={"04.05.2000..."}
              onChangeText={setUserBirth}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Doğum Yeri"} 
              yazialani={"Eskişehir..."}
              onChangeText={setUserFrom}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Yaşadığı İl"} 
              yazialani={"Konya..."}
              onChangeText={setUserLivein}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Üniversite"} 
              yazialani={"Konya Teknik Üniversitesi..."}
              onChangeText={setUserUni}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Bölümü"} 
              yazialani={"Bilgisayar Mühendisliği..."}
              onChangeText={setUserDepartment}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Yetenekleri"} 
              yazialani={"Görsel Hafıza,Valorant Rank Kasma..."}
              onChangeText={setUserSkills}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Kullanılan Teknolojiler"} 
              yazialani={"Blender,Unity,3DsMax,React-Native..."}
              onChangeText={setUserUsetech}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Daha Önce Çalışılan Yer"} 
              yazialani={"PigaSoft..."}
              onChangeText={setUserWork}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Projeleri"} 
              yazialani={"CvAPP,VRAPP..."}
              onChangeText={setUserProject}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye GİT Hesabı"} 
              yazialani={"Git Link..."}
              onChangeText={setUserGit}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Linkedn Hesabı"} 
              yazialani={"Linkedn Link..."}
              onChangeText={setUserLinkedn}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye İnstagram Hesabı"} 
              yazialani={"İnstagram Link..."}
              onChangeText={setUserInstagram}
            />
            <Input 
              label={"Üye Maili"} 
              yazialani={"Gmail Link..."}
              onChangeText={setUserMail}
            />

            <Button text={"Kaydı Tamamla"} onPress={handleSubmit}/>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

export default SignUP;
```

ProfileInfo.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

function ProfileInfo({ route }){
    const {user} = route.params;

    return(
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.complete}>KAYIT BAŞARILI</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Üye Şehri: {user.userName}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Üye Adı: {user.userLast}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Üye Soyadı: {user.userNumber} </Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Üye Doğum Tarihi: 
 {user.userBirth}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Üye Doğum Yeri: 
 {user.userfrom}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Üye Yaşadığı İli: 
 {user.userlivein}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    label: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 15,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        color: 'black',
        margin: 5,
    },
    complete: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 50,
        color: 'black',
        margin: 10
    }
})
export default ProfileInfo;
```

How can I fix error?

I take this error:

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload
> {"name":"Drawer","params":{"screen":"ProfileInfo","params":{"user":{"userName":"a","userLast":"a","userNumber":"a","userBirth":"a","userfrom":"a","userlivein":"a"}}}}
> was not handled by any navigator.
>
> Do you have a screen named 'Drawer'?

or user undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to effect a navigation change to the dashboard screen that renders a `Drawer` component.

```
<BottomTab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Drawer} />
```

Try using `"Dashboard"` for the screen name instead:

```js
navigation.navigate(
  'Dashboard',
  { screen: 'ProfileInfo', params: { user } }
);
```